# git send-mail for gmail

Tags: git, gmail

A few months ago Google disable allowing less secured apps to be used to increase security. Here is what it says:

> To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no
> longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you
> to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and
> password.

Is there a way to use `git send-email` with `gmail` now?

Comment: Does that also include setting up 3-rd party _passwords_ through myaccount.google.com -> security -> app paswords? :-O I see that at least the UI is there, won't go as far as send me a patch just to make sure.

Comment: @eftshift0 not sure if there is such a config option...

Comment: What do you mean? That is what I use when I want to send a patch with `git send-email`. I setup a new app password there and it works like a charm.... at least, it **did** work like a charm, not sure if your comment is related to phasing out **this** feature.

Comment: @eftshift0 I mean I don't see anything related to create a token on the https://myaccount.google.com/security tab. There is "Third party apps with account access" menu, but it does not allow creating access token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use an app password for authentication.  However, this requires that you've enabled 2FA (which you should do anyway).  Once you've done that, you can go to https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords to create the app password, as specified in the `git send-email` manual page.

I'm not aware of any way to do this without enabling 2FA if Google no longer allows the "Less secure apps" setting.