Unable to send email using git send-email using gmail SMTP server
I am getting below error while sending email using git send-email using SMTP server, although the password is correct and the sender and recipient is the same, its failing.
Command ran:
git send-email --to 123@gmail.com --from 123@gmail.com *.patch 0001-TEST.patch

.gitconfig file:
[sendemail]
    smtpEncryption = tls
    smtpserver = smtp.gmail.com
    smtpuser = 123@gmail.com
    smtpServerPort = 587
    smtppass = test
[user]
    name = Salman
    email = 123@gmail.com



If it is your Google account's password, it won't work. You need to use a password that is provided when you grant access as an external application (in account security, if I recall correctly).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73213378/git-send-mail-for-gmail Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+gmail+send-mail

You need to use an apps password

Thanks @eftshift0 , Linda,  it worked, can you also suggest how to disable the default y/n prompt that is displayed with patch commit message while sending the mail ?
